# Why the nuclear fusion 6Li+D and 7Li+P reactions happens 10 time less than H+11B?

Tags: nuclear-physics, fusion, scattering-cross-section

The first two reactions generates 2 alphas and the boron one generates 3, but boron has 2 more protons than lithium so should repels more to hydrogen.
I suppose is a question of nuclear states, but surprises me very much the difference.

Note: There are few reaction data of the B11+P reaction, and following one is a calculated one

[image: Li6+D fusion cross section]
[image: Li7+P fusion cross section]
[image: B11+P fusion cross section]

Comment: Check the nuclear structure data files for the energy levels of the intermediate nucleus asa starting point.

Comment: Do you means in the IAEA live chart? https://www-nds.iaea.org/relnsd/vcharthtml/VChartHTML.html or also at the Exfor database to see the cross section?

Comment: I’d suggest the charts at TUNL for light nuclei. They show all the relative energy levels.

Comment: Thank you Jon, it will be very useful, so I will study if I can (leave me three days, I am full of work). But I do not understand if the energy levels are well quantized within MeV between a stage and other why does not appear resonances in the cross section data accordingly the TUNL step changes. It would help have a equation or graph of forces involved in the kinetics of the particles

Comment: Li6 bind energy=14.1MeV, Li7=14.9 and B11=8.7MeV, so is like the lithiums are more willing to drop energy. In other ways the intermediate levels for Li6+D or Li7+H is Be8 with 4.941MeV and the C12=0, so the intermediate level of Be8 is more difficult to obtain, but i am not sure of that because I suppose that the Be8 and C12 is not at ground state but I do not find the intermediate state for the B11+P in the TUNL

Comment: FWIW, [$^8Be$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beryllium-8) has a very short half-life: $6.7×10^{-17}$ s.

Comment: Boron is very much *harder* to burn in a star?

Comment: I do not understand: harder than in a laboratory or harder with respect other reactions?. In a star the reactions are made by reaction chains: I do not know about the reaction chains in a star but if boron is part of a reaction chain will be more easy to burn than other elements in the sun and also in laboratory. also it depends if boron is in the same layer than deuterium or hydrogen in the star. I hope an astrophysicist could respond better